# String slice in a const function

Tags: rust, constants, slice

How do you do a string slice in a const function?

```rust
const fn cya_first_char(inc: &str) -> &str {
    &inc[1..]
    //  ~~~~~ Error: cannot call non-const operator in constant functions
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str` doesn't have too many const methods, but `as_bytes` is, and `[u8]` has a const `split_at` method. Then you can turn that back into `str` with `std::str::from_utf8`.

```rust
const fn take_first_bytes_of_str(s: &str, i: usize) -> &str {
    let Ok(s) = std::str::from_utf8(s.as_bytes().split_at(i).1) else {
        panic!("first character was more than one byte");
    };
    s
}

const fn cya_first_char(inc: &str) -> &str {
    take_first_bytes_of_str(inc, 1)
}
```

This will scan the entire rest of the string for validity every time, so it will detrimentally affect performance if called on long strings or when called many times. If that's what you need, then it'll probably be worth reimplementing [`is_char_boundary`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.is_char_boundary) in const and using that with `from_utf8_unchecked`.

Here is one that takes the first character instead of the first byte.

```rust
const fn take_first_char_of_str(s: &str) -> &str {
    let mut i = 1;

    while i < 5 {
        let (first, rest) = s.as_bytes().split_at(i);
        if std::str::from_utf8(first).is_ok() {
            // SAFETY: if `first` is valid UTF-8, then `rest` is valid UTF-8
            unsafe {
                return std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(rest);
            }
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    unreachable!()
}

const fn cya_first_char(inc: &str) -> &str {
    take_first_char_of_str(inc)
}
```

This one gets around the performance issue by only checking the first character for validity, and assuming the rest. This way, it only has to check at most *1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10* bytes for any length of string.

This is still not ideal, but will run in constant time.

Comment: this wouldn't work if the first character is more than one byte.

Comment: @kalkronline correct. It's the same as yours.

Comment: oh, hm, I didn't realize that indexing into a string doesn't do it across chars..

Comment: @kalkronline I added another method that takes one character.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a lot of const fn in `&str` for now. If you want you can use array and [`from_utf8()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) that is const and test how robust is rustc using some recursive:

```rust
// cause brute force is sometime more simple
const fn cya_first_char_aux(inc: &[u8]) -> &str {
    match inc {
        [_, rest @ ..] => match std::str::from_utf8(rest) {
            Ok(s) => s,
            _ => cya_first_char_aux(rest),
        },
        _ => "",
    }
}

const fn cya_first_char(inc: &str) -> &str {
    cya_first_char_aux(inc.as_bytes())
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", cya_first_char("Hello world!"));
    println!("{}", cya_first_char("老虎 Léopard"));
    println!("{}", cya_first_char(""));
}
```